# Это Леопольд(,) Аристархов Михайлович

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятушончонки?

`Леопольд(,) Аристархов Михайлович(,) – довольно небезынтересный англоговорящий коток, однако.`

`Это Леопольд(,) Аристархов Михайлович.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны несколько вариантов:

***Леопольд, Аристархов Михайлович, – довольно небезынтересный англоговорящий коток, однако*** (1);

***Леопольд Аристархов Михайлович – довольно небезынтересный англоговорящий коток, однако*** (2);

***Это Леопольд, Аристархов Михайлович*** (1);

***Это Леопольд Аристархов Михайлович*** (2).

В вариантах, помеченных единицей, играет свою роль **присоединительная конструкция**, то есть фамилию и оьчество автор хотел просто присоединить к предложению.

В вариантах же, помеченных цифрой 2, нет ни пауз, ничего. То есть ФИО человека является **цельным подлежащим**.

---

**ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ.**

Впрочем, думаю, возможно и такое деление на синтагмы:

***ЛеопОльд/ Аристархов МихАйлович —/ довольно небезынтересный англоговорящий коток, однако***;

***Это ЛеопОльд/ Аристархов МихАйлович***.

---

Вывод: если есть паузы, берите первый или третий вариант. Но если нет и вы подражумеваете ФИО как единое подлежащее — запятые можно не ставить.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%A4.%20%D0%98.%20%D0%9E